# Show $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,-y)$ is a group homomorphism?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-homomorphism

> Show that $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,-y)$ is a group homomorphism from $E$
>   to itself where $E$ is an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form.

So $E$ is of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Would I just show that any point $P \in E$ maps to $-P$ and this operation is always perserved? How does this being an elliptic curve alter this basic problem? What's a good way to show that this mapping is a group homomorphism?

Comment: You need to show that this mapping (call it $\Phi$) respects the group operation, that is $\Phi(P\oplus Q) = \Phi(P) \oplus \Phi(Q)$ for all $P,Q \in E$.

Comment: @HansEngler so for Elliptic curves is $\oplus$ just addition..?

Comment: It's the group law for this particular elliptic curve.

Comment: What kind of background do you have? There are several different ways to show this, but some will fit better than others depending on where you encountered this problem.

Comment: Do you know the chord-and-tangent process for adding points on $E$? Do you know that under this process, the points of $E$ become a commutative group?